# How to refresh an observable in ionic 4 after manipulating it

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to filter results in my ionic 4 application.  I have a ionic list that is displaying results from an observable that I set in the ngOnInit.  I also have a searchbar on the page that calls a search function.  I can capture the input and it's passing input but it doesn't look like it's filtering or possibly not updating the ion-list.

I've tried numerous iterations of the search function and the filter function but no results.  I've tried it with the (ionchanged) and (ionInput) and currently I console.log the input coming in and that works but the ion-list never updates.

HTML file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Hospitals</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="searchChanged($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list *ngIf="results">
    <ion-item button *ngFor="let item of (results | async)" routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/hospital-details/'+ item.id]">
      <ion-label text-wrap>
        <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GetHospitalsService } from '../../services/get-hospitals.service';
import { SearchPipe } from './../../search.pipe';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-hospitals',
  templateUrl: './hospitals.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hospitals.page.scss'],
})
export class HospitalsPage implements OnInit {

  // information = null;
  hospitals = null;
  searchTerm = '';

  results: Observable<any>;
  information: Observable<any>;


  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private hospitalService: GetHospitalsService, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Hospitals enter');

    this.results = this.hospitalService.getHospitals1();
    this.information = this.filterArr2(this.searchTerm);

  }
  filterArr2(search): Observable<any> {
    console.log('enter the filterArr2');
    console.log('this.results', this.results);
    return this.results.pipe(
          // map(oneObj => oneObj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
          map(data => data.filter(data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1))
      );
  }

  searchChanged($event) {
    console.log('search changed entered');
    this.searchTerm = $event.target.value;
    console.log('search term passed', this.searchTerm);
    const mySearch = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    console.log('search lower', mySearch);
    this.information = this.filterArr2(mySearch);
  }


}
```

I would expect it to return the filtered observable and for the results to be updated, but alas, it does not.  The results stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you set

```
  this.results = this.hospitalService.getHospitals1();
```

in your `ngOnInit`. This is a one-time set, and the Observable will start (because of the `async` `pipe` in your HTML), retrieve data and complete. It is then no longer active.

If you want to refresh or pass on separate parameters to your API for retrieval (like you would with search), you need to reset your `this.results` variable to a new Observable to retrieve data and complete.

Because of the `AsyncPipe` you're already using, you don't have to rebind or switch to another disposable Observable, faking a constant stream of data; instead the `AsyncPipe` will switch to your new Observable upon rebinding.

So if you create a function to `retrieveHospitals()` in your component, in that function do something like:

```
this.results = this.hospitalService.getHospitals1()
```

and call that function from your component or your HTML, it'll retrieve a new list and show that.

Hope I've helped you with this.